# phpexcel can't get not empty value

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I use phpexcel to read a table,but sometimes it can't get value which is not empty.

```
            import('ORG.PHPExcel');
            import('ORG.PHPExcel.IOFactory');
            import('ORG.PHPExcel.Reader.Excel5');
            import('PHPExcel.Reader.Excel2007');
            $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();          
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    //use excel2007
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();              
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($uploadfile);           

            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1);
            $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
            var_dump($highestRow);

            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn(); 
            var_dump($highestColumn);

            $count=0;
            $zzdw = M('zzdw');
            for($j=4;$j<=$highestRow;$j++)
            {           
                $count++;
                $flag=0;
                $b= (string)$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("B".$j)->getValue();
                if($b==''){
                  echo('<font color="red"><strong>'.$count.'</strong></font>');
                  var_dump($b);
                  exit;
                }
            }
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv27X.jpg)

like this, row and col have value,but can't get cell's value.
  some files don't have this problem,some have.
  file format error？I use ".xls".

Comment: can you show some error log? or you can see [problem1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048803/php-excel-reader-2-read-cant-read-column-if-not-filled) [problem2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028471/how-to-read-empty-cells-in-phpexcel-without-skipping-values) [problem3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285511/ignore-empty-cells-phpexcel)

Comment: Is there any VBA populating cell values in the worksheet? PHPExcel won't run VBA for you

Comment: But unless you can provide more information about your spreadsheet file, your question can't be answered

Comment: And just because a fle has a `.xls` extension, that doesn't guarantee that it's a BIFF-format `.xls` file; and trying to load a file that isn't BIFF-format using the `Excel5` Reader will give format errors..... why not let PHPExcel detect the file format and select the correct Reader?